# List.toArray(Object[]) performance

Tags: java, performance, toarray

I'm getting a `List` of object **A**, then I use `Apache Commons Collection4` to transform the obtained `List` from having **A** instances to having **B** instances.

```
    listOfBs = (List<B>) CollectionUtils.collect(listOfAs, componentTransformer);
```

However, eventually I need to have an `Array` of **Bs** not a `List`.

So my question is, which is faster.

1. Convert the list using `CollectionUtils.collect`
2. Create an array using `listOfBs.toArray(new B[listOfBs.size()])`

Or

1. Loop over the `listOfAs`
2. Transform each **A** object to a **B** object
3. Add each **B** object to an array (**B[]**)

The difference between the first approach and the second approach is that the first approach has much less code, but I'm not sure if the **toArray** method bares a hidden loop or expensive operations.

What I see in the second approach is that I'm sure I'll loop only once over the `listOfAs` list.

So which approach is **faster** ?

Comment: Why not transform and collect into an array in one step? You are not forced to use `CollectionUtils`. Even better, just use Java 8.

Comment: I can't use Java 8 at the moment, although I'd like to know the name of feature that Java 8 offers for this. I can loop and transform the objects but less code is better. So if `toArray` doesn't cause a big performance hit, I may use it.

Comment: i dont think there is big difference, when you have a look at code `CollectionUtils.collect`  it is looping through list and transforming object, which is your first two steps from your alternative method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't be concerned about performance of [List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), its complexity is *linear* as it will resort to a single loop internally.

As it is implemented with [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29), which eventually comes to [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), that is implemented in native code it could be potentially even faster than a java-level loop.

Comment: What do you mean by linear ?

Comment: What I mean is that performance(time) is proportional to input size because it is based on a single loop.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana as opposed to quadratic etc. linear basically means no nested loops.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting to read is this article:http://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/#_conclusion

It goes into great detail about the different ways to convert a List to an array.

Conclusion: do not use `listOfBs.toArray(new B[listOfBs.size()])` as stated by you, but use `listOfBs.toArray(new B[0])`.

Believe it or not, this is faster.